# Force.com site as javascript script

Tags: visualforce, javascript, force.com, force.com-sites

Is there any way to make a force.com site write JavasScript only?

I have the following which ALMOST gets me what I want, but there's I still get the `<head>` tag as part of the document. Is there a way to remove that `<HEAD>` tag?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" 
    sidebar="false"
    controller="custom_controller"
    standardStylesheets="false"
    applyBodyTag="false"
    applyHtmlTag="false"
    docType="html-5.0"
>
<script type="text/javascript">

    <apex:repeat value="{!events}" var="event">
        document.write('<li><apex:outputText value="{!event.name}"></apex:outputText></li>');
    </apex:repeat>    
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I'm confused. You have a `<script>` tag but the repeater is emitting HTML.

Comment: @MikeChale Actually, they're trying to write a JS file that has a bunch of `document.write` calls in it.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I was trying to include data from SF in our website. At first I had an iframe, but I couldn't control the height of the iframe. Now the VF page is actually writing the content and the height won't be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specified HTML5, so you're emitting HTML5. Instead, use this set of markup:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="custom_controller"
    standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false"
    showHeader="false" contentType="text/javascript">
    <apex:repeat value="{!events}" var="event">
        document.write('<li><apex:outputText value="{!event.name}"></apex:outputText></li>');
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Specifying DOCTYPE makes the page an HTML page, not JavaScript. If your intent is to use it as a JavaScript file (e.g. via includeScript), you must not specify DOCTYPE, and you must specifically inhibit any HTML rendering with the appropriate tags, and you must also set the content type to JavaScript so it will interpret correctly. Also, JavaScript files never use a `script` tag, because they are assumed to be JavaScript already-- `script` is an HTML construct that tells the HTML renderer that the contents are JavaScript within an HTML page.

Comment: Thanks! The only issue in your code is showSidebar="false" should only read sidebar="false"

Comment: @penaservices I always mistype that one. Fixed it for the future.